# Qt: How to clear setFixedSize after it's been set

Tags: c++, qt, resize

I currently have a form that might need to be resize later on. Initially when the Form(QDialog) is created the setFixedSize Method is called. In certain circumstances later the form might have to be resized. Is there anyway which we could disable this method and re-enable it again from inside the QDialog ?

Answer (score 9):

setFixedSize() sets the min and max sizes to the same values therefore stopping re-sizing. So I believe you just have to reset the minimum and maximum sizes by calling:

```
setMinimumSize(...);
```

and

```
setMaximumSize(...);
```

Example if you set minimum size to 0,0 and maximum to the size of your screen / parent then you should have full resizing available to you...

Comment: More correctly: set the minimum to `0`, and the maximum to `QWIDGETSIZE_MAX`.