# Resizable window after fixed size

Tags: qt, resize, widget

I set up fixed size for window:

```
w.setFixedSize(200, 400);
```

Now my window is not resizable. Ok, i want to do it resizabe again:

```
w.resize(200, 400);
```

But it's not working. So, how can i do it resizable or remove fixed size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Qt documentation:[QLayout Class Reference](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qlayout.html#id-11b9b6cb-af29-4e9e-bc8c-1ad992af1f23)

> sizeConstraint : SizeConstraint

This property holds the resize mode of the layout

The default mode is SetDefaultConstraint.

Access functions:

```
SizeConstraint sizeConstraint () const
void setSizeConstraint ( SizeConstraint )
```

SizeConstraint is an enum with this possible values:

> enum QLayout:: SizeConstraint { SetDefaultConstraint , SetNoConstraint , SetMinimumSize , SetFixedSize , SetMaximumSize , SetMinAndMaxSize , Auto , FreeResize , Minimum , Fixed SetFixedSize ...}

you can use SetDefaultConstraint or  SetNoConstraint or ... for your situation.

Comment: this didn't work for me, so I'll leave here another answer just in case http://stackoverflow.com/a/20526604/692829